# Alekhine's defence: Exchange variation 5.e5?

Tags: opening, alekhines-defense

After a brief study over the exchange variation in the Alekhine's defence, On the fifth move Black can choose an extremely sharp line with e5 but i couldn't find it anywhere explained as either a bad or good move or even played.

Comment: Welcome to Chess SE! Can you please tell us what your actual *question* is?

Comment: If the variation could be considered viable.

Comment: Where did you see this 5...e5 idea? If we are talking about the same position, to me it seems that black just loses a pawn for nothing.

Comment: Could you post the exact line you are talking about?

Comment: Have you think 2.e5 Nd5 3.d4 d6 4.c4 Nb6 5.exd6 e5? Usually 5...cxd6 or 5...exd6 is recommended, 5...e5 may continue with 6.dxe5 cxd6 7.exd6 Bxd6 - allowing White to control d4 with strong influence of knight. e5 more often played after g6-Bg7 as fianchetto followed by Bg4.

Answer (score 1):

It's losing for Black because 6.c5 N(6)-d7 7. dxe!  Black can't capture the pawn on e5 because 8. f4! wins a piece (e.g., 8. ... Nd7 9. Qe2+) so Black must play 7. Nxc5 and after 8. Bf4 White's pawn on d6 is a dagger in Black's heart.  The chess engines say White is winning.